# Optimize windows 2008 performance

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, svn, optimization, teamcity

I have windows server 2008 sp2 installed as virtual machine on my personal laptop. I use it only for source control (visual svn) and continuous integration (teamcity). As the virtual machine resources are limited I'd like to optimize it's performance by disabling services and features that are not necessary for my purposes.

Can anyone recommend where to start or provide with tips for getting better performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any profiling on you 2k8 guest?

Comment: @tegbains - no, not sure how to do that.

Comment: For a casual look, look at Resource Monitor. It will help guide you to any immediate bottlenecks. Also, use Performance Monitor and add counters for Physical Disk, Avg Queuing Length, Pages/s, Memory, etc

Answer (score 0):

First and for most, if you haven't already done so install the supporting drivers/software that came with your virtualization software of choice.

Such as:

- VMware Tools for VMware Server/Player/ESX/Workstation/etc
- Virtualbox Guest Additions for VirtualBox

You'll often find graphics and hard drive access will be much slower in a VM without these tools installed.

Comment: Already done that.